# Non iOS Developers rejecting Language Updates/Edit

Tags: discussion

I have tried many times to update Swift code as it evolves but my changes have been rejected many times by non iOS Developers.

Please help.

Comment: It's generally accepted that you should not edit code, for the most part. Instead, in this case, you should be leaving a comment to the author suggesting they update, and if they do not answer, add your own updated answer. For some code-editing guidelines, check out [this meta question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: As a rule of thumb: if someone would need to be a language expert to say whether or not an edit is valid, it's probably too substantial to be an edit.

Comment: Looking at all of your suggested edits, half of those approved shouldn't have been (which is unfortunate, but also unsurprising; reviewers like to approve improper suggested edits).  Edits are not there for you to add or change the content of another user's answer, but rather to improve the presentation of the author's content.

Comment: Okay, got it. I didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Well, stop then.

It's not clear whether you are trying to edit code in questions or answers. If it's the former definitely stop. You could end up removing the very thing that's causing the problem for the OP.

If it's the latter then also stop. There's no need to upgrade an answer to the latest version of Swift or C# or PHP or whatever, *someone* might still be working on that older version.

If you think that using the latest version can produce a better answer **add it yourself**. If others agree you'll get upvotes.

Comment: I think the edits we're talking about are these two answer edits: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8153735 http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8142999 . A comment to the answerer to let them know about the changes might be more appropriate, and I'm thinking that the addition of the exclamation points might not even be the best or safest way to modernize that code. I'd leave that to the answerer, myself.